# C++: What is recommended way to distinguish between string which never had the value set and empty string?

Tags: c++, string

We have a Java messaging API which we are translating to C++.  The messages typically have simple data types, like string, int, double, etc. When a message is constructed, we initialize all the member variables to a default value which the API recognizes as a "null" value (i.e. never set to any value), e.g. `Integer.MAX_VALUE` for int types.  Any fields which are considered null are not serialized and sent.

In Java, strings automatically initialize to `null` so it's easy to differentiate between a string field which is null versus a string which is empty string (which is a legal value to send in the message).

I'm not sure of the best way to handle this in C++, since the strings automatically initialize to an empty string, and empty string is a legal value to send over the API.  We could default strings to some control character (which would not be a legal value in our API), but I'm wondering if there is a more conventional or better way to do this.

We're all new here to C++, so we may have overlooked some obvious approach.

Comment: `boost::optional` seems like a good candidate, and `std::optional` soon.

Comment: also consider using a pointer.

Comment: @andre: would pointers make the API more awkward to use?  meaning a typical way we use this in Java is: `message.companyName = "myco";`.  Would the equivalent using points be: `message.companyName = &("myco");? (Sorry if that's all wrong, I'm a total newbie.)

Comment: @SamGoldberg if you expose the member directly, then yes, it would be more awkward. But you could define getter/setter functions which hide the pointer stuff from the public interface. `boost::optional` would really be the *nicer* solution (apart from what I mention in my answer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *recommended* way is to make is that the object doesn't *exist* until it has a valid value. If a message wit a null string isn't valid, why *allow* it?

You can't avoid it in Java, because a string can always be null.
But C++ gives you the tool to create a class which is guaranteed to *always* hold a string.

And it sounds like that's what you want.

For what you're asking for, the best approach is really to build into the class the invariant that *objects of this class always have a string set*. Instead of setting all the objects to some default value in the constructor, define the constructor to take the actual parameters and set the members to *valid* values.

However, if you want to specify an "optional" value, there are a couple of broad approaches:

- either use a pointer (preferably a smart pointer). A pointer to a string can be null, or it can point to a valid string (which, again, may or may not be empty)
- alternatively, use something like `boost::optional` from the Boost libraries. This is a clever little utility template which lets you define, well, optional values (the object may contain a string, or it may be null)
- or you could simply add a `bool` flag (something like `has_string`, which, when not set, indicates that no string has been set, and the string value should be disregarded).

Personally, I'd prefer the last two approaches, but all three are fairly commonly used, and will work just fine. But the *best* approach is the one in which you design the class so that the *compiler* can guarantee that it'll always be valid. If you don't *want* messages with a null string, let the compiler ensure that messages will never have a null string.

Comment: These are optional fields, so they can't be enforced at compile time, only at run time.  *Optional* is the correct characterization.

Comment: @SamGoldberg I'd go with `boost::optional` then. It's a lightweight and efficient header-only class, and it's easy to use and clearly conveys the desired semantics. Only downside is that you'll get a dependency on Boost, but honestly, most high-quality C++ code has that anyway, and you'll likely need some part of Boost sooner or later no matter what :)

Comment: I'm already using boost asio anyway, so adding another dependency to boost won't hurt.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To replicate Java "things can have values, or lack values", probably the most general way is to store `boost::optional<T>`, or in the next version of the standard, `std::optional<T>`.

You do have to throw in some `*` and `->` if you want to read their values, and be careful about `optional<bool>` because its default conversion to `bool` is "am I initialized or not?", not the `bool` that is stored.  But `operator=` does pretty much what you want it to when writing to it, it is just reading from it that can do unexpected things in a `bool` context.

To tell if an `optional<T>` is initialized, just evaluate it in a `bool` context like you might a pointer.  To extract its value after you have confirmed it is initialized, use the unary `*` operator.

`boost` is a relatively high quality library with a high rate of code migrating from it to the C++ standard in 5 to 10 years.  It does contain some scary parts (like phoenix!), and in general you should make sure that whatever component you are using isn't already in the C++ standard library (having migrated there).  `boost::optional` in particular is part of their header-only libraries, which are easier to use (as you don't have to build `boost` to use them).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I started looking at boost optional today.